# Laravel - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

Hello i'm having this error on my laravel 9 application:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
delete from
  `users`
where
  `id` = 1
```

My code

```
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user)               
    <tr class="text-center">
        <th>#{{$user->id}}</th>
        <td>{{$user->code}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->updated_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->updated_at}}</td>
        <td class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="{{ route('admin.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-warning text-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-pen ms-1"></i></a>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary text-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a>

          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger text-center userDelete"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i></button>
          </div>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="confirmDelete" class="custom-confirm">
              <!-- Modal content -->
              <div class="modal-content text-center">
                  <p>Sei sicuro di voler <span class="text-danger">cancellare</span> l'utente?</p>
                  <form action="{{route('admin.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
                      @csrf
                      @method('DELETE')
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success me-3">Conferma</button>
                      <span class="cancelDelete btn btn-warning">Annulla</span>
                  </form>
              </div>  
          </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Without the modal of confirm it is working with just:

```
   <form action="{{route('admin.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     @method('DELETE')
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success me-3">Conferma</button>
     <span class="cancelDelete btn btn-warning">Annulla</span>
   </form>
```

Why i'm getting that error?

Problem screenshot
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnYUr.png)

Comment: can you share the schema of your table too?

Comment: seems your user model has a dependency on an other table, post your database schema

Comment: You have data in another table that relies on the user id from the users table. You'll need to check your other table schemas and figure out which rely on the users table, then delete that data before you can delete the user data

Comment: All modals have the same `id="confirmDelte"` which is bad practice. You should have the `id` be unique for each user and ensure the trigger of the modal matches the correct modal otherwise if you want to open modal with `id="confirmDelte"` you don't actually know which one is going to be opened

Comment: just look up DELETE CASCADE on mysql and laravel

Comment: the problem is that i'm not passing the $user->id of the row, that's why i'm having always user 1

Comment: Can you share how you are triggering the modal to pop up?

Comment: $('.userDelete').click(function(){
  $('#confirmDelete').show();
})

Comment: Read my initial comment

Answer (score -2):

You have foreign key on table.You need to delete first related row from related table. For example, if we have **`posts`** and **`comment`s** we need to remove from **`comments`** table which is contain post_id. It looks like in code that:

```php
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$comments = Comment::where('post_id', $id)->delete();

$post->delete();
```

Comment: Wouldn't disabling the constraints leave stale/unrelated data in the database?

Comment: I know it. But  he hasn't introduce that problem here.

Comment: Why not also remove the related data then? This answer kind of solves one problem but introduces a different one

Comment: if i dump $user->id on each table row i get correct ID, but if i want to make a js confirm button and inside it i put the delete form the $user->id assumes the first ID, in this case 1

Comment: i updated the question and add an image

Comment: Okay i changed my answer